# Regex to skip a word in a sentence

Tags: c#, regex

I have a sentence e.g:

> The product must be shipped by 25-Dec-2015 Time: 12:30:00

What I would like to do is capture the date/time but not with the word "Time:" in the answer. So the capture group would contain
`25-Dec-2015 12:30:00`

I've had a try with lookaheads and lookbehinds but without any success.

Comment: Will the characters " Time: " _always_ be present in exactly that format, ie will it always be `dd-MMM-yyyy Time: HH:mm:ss`?  Also, what language/regex engine are you using, as that will affect whether things like lookbehinds are even available.

Comment: can you not have 2 capture groups? and concatenate them later?

Comment: Hi James - yes the characters " Time: " will always be present and the date / time format will be as specified. I'm currently using regex with c# / .net. Thanks.

Comment: Hi dark_ruby. Thanks for the suggestion but I was hoping / wondering whether it could be done in "one hit"?

Comment: If you want to ping users, stick an @ before their name - I only spotted your reply to me as I was still here, for example: @Jazzaid (the author of the post you're commenting on will always get notified, but not other people unless you ping them). [More information here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Comment: If the message will use this format every time, then you do not need a regular expression. Split by space?

Answer (score 1):

You can use groups to capture the date and time separately :

```
(\d{1,2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{4}) Time: (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})
```

Here the whole match is `25-Dec-2015 Time: 12:30:00` but you can access to the first group `25-Dec-2015` and the second group `12:30:00`.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern:

```
^.*\s+(\d\d-...-2\d\d\d)\s+Time:\s+(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)
```

Will find both substrings and split them into groups.

If your next step includes programming you can concatenate them again.

Here is a C# example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string pattern = @"^.*\s+(\d\d-...-2\d\d\d)\s+Time:\s+(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)";
        string input = "The product must be shipped by 25-Dec-2015 Time: 12:30:00";

        Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

        string date = match.Groups[1].Value;
        string time = match.Groups[2].Value;

        string concatenated = date + " " + time;
        Console.WriteLine(concatenated);

    }
```

Note that Regex != Regex. depending on the implementation there are differences.

Jeffrey E. F. Friedl wrote an excellent book on the topic.

Comment: I don't think you need to match the beginning of the string, so you could skip the `^.*` of your regex